# onPause() before onStopped() in activity life cycle

Tags: android, android-activity

In Andoid Acitivity life cycle, why does an activity go through `onPause()` before going to `onStopped()`? Why can't the state go directly to `onStopped()`?

Answer (score 3):

Paused and stopped are related but different states. From the point of view of the user, a paused activity cannot be interacted with, but may still be visible (e.g. if it has called a different Activity as a dialog). A stopped activity is guaranteed to be not visible at all (the uses is in another Activity or even a different app).

[image]

Of course, stopped implies paused, but the reverse is not the case.

From the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

> - If an activity in the foreground of the screen (at the top of the stack), it is *active* or *running*.
> - If an activity has lost focus but is still visible (that is, a new non-full-sized or transparent activity has focus on top of your
>     activity), it is *paused*. A paused activity is completely alive (it
>     maintains all state and member information and remains attached to the
>     window manager), but can be killed by the system in extreme low memory
>     situations.
> - If an activity is completely obscured by another activity, it is *stopped*. It still retains all state and member information, however, it is no longer visible to the user so its window is hidden and it
>     will often be killed by the system when memory is needed elsewhere.

An even more detailed explanation is given in the [Managing the Activity Lifecycle article](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) in the Training section of the Android Developers site.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to the documentation on Activities:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

onPause()

*"Called when the system is about to start resuming a previous activity. This is typically used to commit unsaved changes to persistent data, stop animations and other things that may be consuming CPU, etc. Implementations of this method must be very quick because the next activity will not be resumed until this method returns.
Followed by either onResume() if the activity returns back to the front, or onStop() if it becomes invisible to the user."*

**Note:** I would say "resuming **another** activity" instead of "resuming **a previeous** activity".

onStop()

*"Called when the activity is no longer visible to the user, because another activity has been resumed and is covering this one. This may happen either because a new activity is being started, an existing one is being brought in front of this one, or this one is being destroyed.
Followed by either onRestart() if this activity is coming back to interact with the user, or onDestroy() if this activity is going away."*

Answer (score 2):

Because the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) says so :-)

And it makes sense. The app is open and the user pressed the home button: `onPause()` gets called. After a while the system needs the memory and closes the app: `onStop()` gets called.

Answer (score 0):

Because, onPaused() is executed when your App is rotated or a Dialog is open.
onStop() when your App is not in the screen, so is necesary that this two points in the lifecycle to the user or programmer can identify what action is executed.